# I am unable to convert Map to POJO in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, class, hashmap, objectmapper

I have a POJO that looks like this -

```
public class MyClass {
private String id;

private List<String> titles;
}
```

And the map (myClassMap)-

```
"a" -> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

What I tried -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myClass = mapper.convertValue(myClassMap, MyClass.class);
```

But it returned null for both `id` and `titles`

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: `{"id": "something", "titles": ["one", "two", "three"]}` should give you an object `MyClass` with `id` = `something` and `titles` = `["one", "two", "three"]`

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that mapping you don’t need ObjectMapper, which is indeed a Jackson mapper usually used for JSON mapping and not as a mapper from map to object (which would actually work but not as you expect, because the map keys must match object attributes).
For your case you can simply do the following (assuming a constructor with both attributes in MyClass):

```java
myClassMap.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new MyClass(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

This would create a list of `MyClass` instances, one for each key in `myClassMap`.